# Connection between spark and tableau on tableau desktop

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to connect the spark to tableau, I had installed Simba ODBC driver for 64bit, but I am facing issues while connrecting to spark.

ERROR:
Unable to connect to the ODBC Data Source. Check that the necessary drivers are installed and that the connection properties are valid.
[Simba][ODBC] (10000) General error: Unexpected exception has been caught.

In some doc, I saw that tableau requires some special license key. Can you please explain it

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in this document - http://downloads.tableau.com/beta/Tableau%20Spark%20SQL%20Setup%20Instructions.pdf? As per this document, you do need a special key and the document also provides the contact to obtain this.

Comment: yes I went through but no use he is not replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically spark works with the hive but with difference engine(algorithm for fetching data)

so initially to connect spark from tableau we need to install ODBC Hive drivers then spark driver.

Hive Driver:
http://www.tableau.com/support/drivers

Spark driver :
https://databricks.com/spark/odbc-driver-download

while installing spark  on your cluster we need to configure thrift server with the hive server and need to give new port address.

you can go through using link to install spark in ambari :
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_spark-guide/content/ch_installing-spark.html

And the respective port address need to be specified in tableau while connecting.

If your Cluster is secured with user name and password we need to specify the Authentication as "USERNAME AND PASSWORD" and need to give credentials there..

Even though if it raises error, then look into below areas:

- An incorrect port and/or service defined in the connection
- Web Proxy or Firewall settings are blocking connection from Tableau Desktop
- The data server is not started.